# Embed many websites with absolute paths

Tags: html

I have been given the task to embed a bunch of small websites into a larger website on our main domain.

The problem is that the small websites previously each had their own domain and were programmed with absolute paths. They will stop working if they are simply copied into subdirectories next to the main website.

Additional constraints:

1. The absolute paths can not be replaced automatically, since some of them are generated with JavaScript. A few parts of the unminified source code have been lost, so it would be extremely painful to fix.
2. The chances are good that this stuff will never be touched again. It has been decided that it should not be fixed in a proper way since *"that would be waste of time"*.
3. It should be easy to add additional small websites.

I came up with the idea to create a subdomain for each website, but that violates constraint 3, because it would involve bothering the people responsible for DNS whenever a new website is added.

Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to write a one-off program that I can point at a directory, and all it does is open the javascript files that have the absolute paths, and replace them with a relative path.  A little bit of complexity in writing the program, but then super simple after that.

As for the simplicity in adding new sites, it depends a little on how these sites are hosted.  If they're all retaining their own hosts, bugging the DNS people might be necessary no matter what.  If they are being moved to the host server to live in the same directory structure as the main website, you can just put them in subdirectories so it looks a little like...

```
http://maindomain.com/
http://maindomain.com/subsite1/
http://maindomain.com/foobar/
http://maindomain.com/imspecial/
http://maindomain.com/shopping/
```

Adding a new site would then just be a matter of sticking another directory in there with it's own site code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It does not quite work for my case since some URLs really are being generated in code and are not written in plaintext. For example, one function might join strings to create a URL. Another function might parse the URL from the result of an API request. Nevertheless, your answer could still be useful for other people with fewer restrictions. This one-liner to remove the first `/` in URLs like `"/foo"` might serve as a good starting point: `find -name '*.html' -exec perl -i -pe 's/"\/(.*?)"/"\1"/' {} \;`

Comment: Ah... then DNS might still be of help.  As long as you still have the original domain names, you can set them to point to the new location.  And then new sites being added just shouldn't use absolute path solutions.  Hopefully only have to bug the DNS people once per legacy site.  Sorry I didn't have a better option for you.

Comment: And actually, those absolute paths could still likely be replaced.  Anything with "https://" or the possible variants could be made to return an empty string.  The original domain name could be replaced with the new relative directory you want to put that site in.  Then just leave the directory structure intact.  The replace program could still work right?